# Passing a dynamic URL from Inmobi to MoSync hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, c++, cookies

I am developing a hybrid app for Android in **JavaScript** and **C++**.

I am using `MoSync` and `Inmobi`. I receive the ads from Inmodi server, but I do not succeed to capture the cookie and open it in a default browser.

The links to *GoogleStore* are broken.

I am very new to this monetizing.

Can somebody please give me a code example to how to capture the dynamically passed cookie as a string in MoSync and how to pass it from my Index.html and to main.cpp?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey. I'm from InMobi. There is a chance that the InMobi SDK for MoSync is outdated. Since you're building in Android can you use the InMobi Android SDK directly ?

Comment: Hello and thank you for answering. The SDK I have is InMobi_Android_SDK_4.5.1.

Comment: Hm. So are you using the Android SDK or the SDK for web? The Android SDK doesn't have anything to do with cookies. I'm not sure what you're referencing. This is the integration doc for Android: https://www.inmobi.com/support/integration/23817448/22051163/android-sdk-integration-guide/

Comment: Thank you very much for the file.It is not possible to implement this within MoSync since it is not Java based, but I see now that Android SDK is outdated there. I will switch to Cordova.You where absolutely right that referencing was not done correctly.

Comment: Glad to be of help! Good luck with the app :)